# How to implement mailchimp plugin to target different mailists?

Tags: plugin-mailchimpsubscribe

I'd like to be able to have multiple (2) Mailchimp subscribe forms on the same web site. Each would target different mail lists so I can use one on a landing page for example. I've noticed that the target mail list is set in the List ID field in the plugin settings. Can I simply add another installation of the plugin at this level to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You can't install multiple instances of a plugin. You'd have to duplicate and rename the plugin, and all of its files, class references, and so forth, which I don't recommend doing.

Comment: Thought so... Thx Mr. Lewis - looking forward to mtg u at some point with Mrs. Flinger!

Comment: Apparently you're "the main reason to visit Canada." No pressure.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin in question is my [MailChimp Subscribe plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft), you can easily target different lists by adding a hidden field called `lid` to your form with your list ID:

`<input type="hidden" name="lid" value="2fd6ec09cf">`

This will override the config setting (see the examples under configuration in the repo for more information on this).

Comment: Awesome - thx - didn't see this documented anywhere?

Comment: It's in the configuration part of the documentation, after the first example: `If you have multiple lists you want users to subscribe to, each form can have a hidden field with a name of "lid" and the "value" as your list id. The plugin will use this list id on form submit.`

Comment: Ooo-eeer missus!, looks like I've goofed. It's the Solpace FreeForm plugin I'm referring to. I was using your's before and still have this installed. Will likely revert to this... thx so much André

Comment: Apparently this feature has been removed in v 3.x of the plugin. https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft/blob/craft3/CHANGELOG.md#removed